# Errors Thrown When Inserting Data After Tag or Edge is Created

Tags: docker, nebula-graph

I'm using nebula docker but it throws me an error when I connected first. Then I retried everything is ok. Why is that? Must I retry every time?

Answer (score 0):

This is likely caused by setting the `heartbeat_interval_secs` value to fetch data from the meta server. Conduct the following steps to resolve:

If meta has registered, check `heartbeat_interval_secs` value in console with the following command.

```
nebula> GET CONFIGS storage:heartbeat_interval_secs
nebula> GET CONFIGS graph:heartbeat_interval_secs
```

If the value is large, change it to 1s with the following command.

```
nebula> UPDATE CONFIGS storage:heartbeat_interval_secs=1
nebula> UPDATE CONFIGS graph:heartbeat_interval_secs=1
```

> Note the changes take effect in the next period.